# How can classes be passed by reference in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, reference, unsafe

As we all know, classes in .NET are passed by reference and structs by value.

In unsafe code, you can have pointers to structs, but not to classes since they are moved by the GC. When you have a pointer to an array, for example, you either have to put it in a `fixed` statement (if you allocated on the heap) or `stackalloc` (to allocate on the stack).

With that said, how is it possible for classes to be passed by reference if they are moved by the GC?

Comment: @SamAxe All parameters are pass by value by default including object

Comment: @johnny5: err, yes.  My mistake on that part.  I'll adjust it.

Comment: "classes" are a language construct that have no meaning beyond the source code. A class compiles to a type. A type can be instantiated as an object, and passed around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the GC moveth; the GC fixeth. Since the GC has to *find* all references to an object anyway (to see if it's GC'able), it's a small extra step to *change* those references to point to the new address.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of class type instance as a handle, then a reference to handle would be just one more indirection (sort of a pointer to handle) **limited in scope** by a method call. Since the object itself remains hidden behind a handle it can be relocated without any visible effect.